# Is there a way to plot a circular chart (as a target) in Python?

Tags: python, plot, artificial-intelligence

I'm building an Artificial Neural Network and I implemented the K-fold Cross Validation to Evaluate the model by the mean and the variance of the accuracies returned by these method.

Now I want to plot four circular charts (as a target) to "illustrate" the category of Bias-Variance Tradeoff in which the model is, depending on the values of variance and accuracy.

There's a way to do this in Python?

Comment: Have a look at the [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html), it'll probably have something similar to what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a simple example

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  


labels = ['USA', 'China', 'India', 'Japan', 'Germany', 'Russia', 'Brazil', 'UK', 'France', 'Italy']

quants = [15094025.0, 11299967.0, 4457784.0, 4440376.0, 3099080.0, 2383402.0, 2293954.0, 2260803.0, 2217900.0, 1846950.0]
def draw_pie(labels,quants):

    plt.figure(1, figsize=(6,6))

    # For China, make the piece explode a bit

    expl = [0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    # Colors used. Recycle if not enough.

    colors  = ["blue","red","coral","green","yellow","orange"]

    # autopct: format of "percent" string;

    plt.pie(quants, explode=expl, colors=colors, labels=labels, 
    autopct='%1.1f%%',pctdistance=0.8, shadow=True)

    plt.title('Top 10 GDP Countries', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})

    plt.show()

draw_pie(labels,quants)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxxea.png)